# Pointer to variable inside a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct{
    char *lexema;
    int comp_lexico;
    union{
        double v;
        double (*fnctptr)();
    } valor;
}tipoelem;

struct celda {
    tipoelem info;
    struct celda *izq, *der;
};

typedef struct celda * abb;
```

Then I define a global variable `abb`, which has a global scope. If I get somehow the memory direction of the field info of `celda`, would I be able to modify it safely or It is better to define the field as a `tipoelem` pointer such as `(tipoelem *info)`?

The thing is, is it safe to edit the `tipoelem info` field with a `tipoelem *pointerToInfo` from other part of the prrogram or it is better to declare it as a pointer `tipoelem *info` in the struct celda?

Edited with more information:
The way I want to modify `tipoelem info` is the next one, and I do not know if it is safe.

```
abb a;
int main(){
    tipoelem *ptr = a->info;
    ptr->comp_lexico = 2;
}
```

Comment: could you reformulate, the question is hard to understand; what quind of code would you like to write, and where in this code do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Don't hide pointers by `typedef`.

Comment: @OznOg edited with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to access like that.
Consider this example,

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stOne {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

struct stTwo {
    struct stOne ObjectOne;
    struct sttwo *pTwo;
};

struct stOne *pOne;
struct stTwo *pTwo;
struct stTwo ObjectstTwo;

int main() {

    pTwo = &ObjectstTwo;   
    pTwo->ObjectOne.c = 'H';
    printf("%c", ObjectstTwo.ObjectOne.c);

    pOne = &pTwo->ObjectOne;
    pOne->c = 'D';
    printf(" %c", ObjectstTwo.ObjectOne.c);
}
```

This code prints

```
H
```

as output.

Similarly you can modify a member of the `struct tipoelem`, for example `comp_lexico` which is an `int`.

```
struct celda objectCelda;

//Assuming abb is a pointer, Make abb point to an object
abb = &objectCelda;

//Modify the value of comp_lexico
abb->info.comp_lexico = 0xAA;
```

Now changing the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct stOne {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

struct stTwo {
  struct stOne ObjectOne;
  struct sttwo *pTwo;
};

struct stOne *pOne;
struct stTwo *pTwo;
struct stTwo ObjectstTwo;

int main() {

    pTwo = &ObjectstTwo;   
    pTwo->ObjectOne.c = 'H';
    printf("%c", ObjectstTwo.ObjectOne.c);

    pOne = &pTwo->ObjectOne;
    pOne->c = 'D';
    printf(" %c", ObjectstTwo.ObjectOne.c);
}
```

This prints

```
H D
```

on console as output. So it is perfectly okay to do it either way.

Comment: It is a bit different. What I want to do is edit object one having `ptOne = &(pTwo->objectOne)` and then `ptOne->c = 'H'`. I do not know if that is safe.

Answer (score 0):

*I define a global variable abb,*

It is not a variable, it is a `type`.

---

As an answer to the question after the edit:-

Now you can use `abb`, as a type similar to `struct celda*`.

After the edit the answer is simply what the problem demands.

For example:

if each instance of the `struct celda` is needed to contain a block information then it is better to allow a pointer to it inside the `structure`. That is a better thing in terms of design where closely related data are kept closely.

And another thing is suppose you keep a pointer to `tipoelem` outside of the structure variable. Then suppose after some time you will need another pointer to `tipoelem` then these two pointer to `tipoelem` is different in meaning. That's why it's better to keep in structure.

Answer (score 0):

To access the *int* inside info with a variable of *type abb* I would use this main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    abb variable;
    printf("comp_lexico es %d",variable->info.comp_lexico);
}
```